# How to run angular code synchronously like I would in c#

Tags: c#, angular, typescript

I am trying to recreate a C# app with Angular, but I am struggling to get the code to run synchronously as it would in c#.

Here is an example:

```
private void doChecks()
{
    if (isInvoiced())
        return;

    Console.WriteLine("Done");
}
```

```
private bool isInvoiced()
{
    var invID = Server.GetInvoice(mAccID);
    if (invID <= 0)
        return false;
    else 
        return someOtherFunction(invID);
}
```

When I try implementing this in Angular I am not sure how to accomplish the same flow without resorting to `async` `await` methods.

```
async doChecks() {
    const doAllChecks = await this.service.DoChecks(this.mAcc).toPromise();

    if (await this.isInvoiced()) {
      return;
    }
    Console.log("Done");
}
```

```
async isInvoiced() {
    const invID = await this.service.GetInvoice(this.mAcc).toPromise();

    if (invID <= 0)
        return false;
    else {
        const data = await someOtherFunction(invID); // now this function is also going to have to be async to I can await inside of that for its http request to finish.
        return data;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this in a simpler way ?

Answer (score 0):

You could run it one after the other inside "then statement". Nested Promises. If you are using Angular 2 and above, you can try nesting your logic in subscribers instead of promises.

```
 this.MyPromise1().then(result => {
    this.MyPromise2().then(result2 => {
    this.MyPromise3().then(result3 => {
     and so on..
    })
    })
    });
```